# How to manually submit a button in asp.net using javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, jquery, webforms

Using javascript, I want to submit a asp.net button, how can I do this?

I know the onclick looks like: javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new .....);

I am also weary because the ID of the control can change.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a control similar to this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Foo" ... />
```

You can something simple like fire the 'click' event in JS while accessing the updated client ID (jQuery syntax here):

```
$('#<%=Foo.ClientID%>').click()
```

Or you could get the proper JS to run like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function clickFoo() {
    <%=Page.ClientScript. GetPostBackEventReference(Foo)%>;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The third version is probably the one we should use, as it asks the framework to generate the exact same script that it uses when it fires events. Even if there will be changes to that script then it will be reflected there as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
var button = document.getElementById('btnID'); 
if (button)
{ 
   button.click();
}
```

If you can put the javascript right in your .aspx markup, then you can get around the changing ID's as well by doing this:

```
var button = document.getElementById('<%= myServerButton.ClientID %>'); 
if (button)
{ 
   button.click();
}
```

When your .aspx is processed, the ID of the button as it appears on the page will be substituted into your javascript function.

Comment: I tried that, but for some reason it is not doing a postback.  Very strange!

Comment: I even did a $(..).attr("href") and it does output the doPost... that is in the href tag of the button.

Answer (score 2):

That is easy you can use __doPostBack function passing the controll ID that  you want the click(command etc) event get fired.

To avoid problems with ID, do something like it:

```
__doPostBack("<%= yourConrol.UniqueID%>");
```

EDIT:
There is an existing .Net Framework method [Page.GetPostBackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.getpostbackeventreference(VS.71).aspx) that emits client-side script that initiates postback and also provides a reference to the control that initiated the postback event.

Answer (score 2):

Using jquery put something like this into your aspx page.

```
$('#<%= myctrl.ClientID %>').click();
```

**myctrl** is the button. The property ClientID gives the id of the html button. Jquery offers the [click](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click) function.

Comment: don't forget the '#' for an id selector

Answer (score 0):

You can either, click a button or submit a form.

So, if you want to click the button,

```
var button = document.getElementById('<%= btnButtonID.ClientID %>');  
if (button) { button.click(); }
```

or to Post the form

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```